# Why is the absolute of the union of the differences of sets greater than the absolute of the difference between the unions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Why is the absolute of the union of the differences of sets  greater than the absolute of the difference between the unions of each of them?

$$
\left| \cup_k G_k \setminus \cup_k E_k \right| \le \left| \cup_k \left(G_k \setminus E_k\right) \right|
$$

Can someone prove this inequality?

Actually, it is easy to accept if I try to substitute some sets. However, I want to prove this mathematically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proving such a result can be done by showing that

$$ (\cup_{k} G_{k} \setminus \cup_{k}E_{k}) \subset \cup_{k} (G_{k} \setminus E_{k})$$

as subsets have cardinality less than or equal to their supersets. Take a point $x$ in the left-hand side. By necessity it sits inside some $G_{i}$ but none of the $E_{k}$. Thus, in particular, it sits inside $G_{i} \setminus E_{i}$, and hence is in the union on the right-hand side.

This proof also shows why the right-hand-side might be strictly larger. On the right-hand side we only throw away from $G_{i}$ that which sits inside $E_{i}$. But on the left-hand side we throw away from $G_{i}$ elements from all $E_{k}$.

Comment: Ah.... good! Thank you. I got some feeling of intuition.